# Extjs 6 - How to use DataIndex in a Grid for Nested Data

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, grid

I have created a fiddle here. My question is how to assign the DataIndex for the Aircraft Name and the Operator Name column.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2qs9

I do not want to do it this way

```
{name: 'operator', type: 'auto'},
{name: 'operatorId', type: 'string', mapping:'operator.id'},
{name: 'operatorName', type: 'string', mapping:'operator.name'}
```

then use operatorName as the DataIndex in the Grid because my original data is even more complicated with arrays and mode nested objects so that would be mean I need to flatten the entire Data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use templatecolumn or renderer in grid to show what you need.

Using templatecolumn:

```
{
        text: 'Aircraft Name',
        tpl: '{aircraft.name}',
        xtype: 'templatecolumn'
}
```

Using renderer:

```
{
        text: 'Aircraft Name - Second Option',
        renderer: function (v, record) {
               return record.getAircraft() ? record.getAircraft().get('name') : null;
        }
}
```

Example on fiddle: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2qsm

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :D